# How to set limits on the number of lines read by stream nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am reading a long csv text and streaming to the client. I need to be able to assure that each stream that is passed on to the client has some kind of line break mark associated with it. The problem is that when I stream data, it strips line breaks. Is there a way I can assure that line breaks are not stripped or it is replaced by some characters that I can recognize as line breaks on the client side 'while' streaming?

Also, there is no guarantee that each buffer in stream will always end at the line break point say for example if I have below data

```
10,20,30
40,50,60
```

The next buffer may start from 50 instead of 40. How do I know each buffer should be concatenated with or without line break?

server side

```
app.get('/test/api', (req, res) => {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./resources/onescsv.csv');
    stream = byline.createStream(stream);
    stream.on('data', (data)=>{
        // console.log(data.toString());
        res.write(data + '||||')
    });
    // stream.pipe(res);
    stream.on('end', () => res.end());

});
```

client side

```
let count = 0;
    $(document).ready(()=>{
        let lastOfPrevious;
        let firstOfCurrent;
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/test/api', true);
        xhr.onprogress = function (){
            console.log('line count');
            let incomingBuffer = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(incomingbuffer)
    };
    xhr.send()
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting chunks by newline in Node.js data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781713/getting-chunks-by-newline-in-node-js-data-stream)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were streaming a very big csv data from your server to client, where in client you were not able to figure out the line breaks in the streamed csv data.

Very easy soultion will be using builtin node module 'readline' which allow us to read stream data line by line. I have added below working code snippet to illustrate this.

*stream_server.js*

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/tmp.csv');
    stream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(8000)
```

*stream_client.js*

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const readline = require('readline');

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000
  };

http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log(`Got response:  ${res.statusCode}`);
    let readStream = readline.createInterface({
        input: res,
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });
    readStream.on('line', function(line) {
        console.log(`Reading -->  ${line}`);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(`Got error  ${e.message}`);
});
```

Hope this will solves your problem ..

I have kept the above part pertaining to my initial understanding of the quesion, with modified phrasing of question looks like you were adding delimiter to each line of the csv in server response.

Well if you define your express route as below it will add delimiter for each line of your csv file

```
app.get('/test/api', (req, res) => {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('./tmp.csv');
    let readStream = readline.createInterface({
        input: stream,
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });
    readStream.on('line', function(line) {
        console.log(`Reading -->  ${line}`);
        res.write(line + ' |||| ')
    });
    stream.on('end', () => res.end());
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question to illustrate my problem. I am already writing to response line by line and expected same behaviour as you did. However, apparently, even if I stream line by line, `xhr` receives chunk of lines at a time